# Deduce that $g(z) = \cos(z)$ maps $\mathbb C / B$ onto $\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $B$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb C$. Prove that $f(z) = e^z$ maps $\mathbb C / B$ onto $\mathbb C / {0}$.

Deduce that $g(z) = \cos(z)$ maps $\mathbb C / B$ onto $\mathbb C$.

So far I have shown:

Let $z=x+yi$ and $w=u+iv=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ ($\rho>0$). Assume that $e^z=w$ and then

$$ e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) $$

from which one has

$$ e^x\cos y=\rho\cos\theta, e^x\sin y=\rho\sin \theta. $$

Thus

$$ x=\frac12\ln\rho,y=\theta+2n\pi, n\in Z.$$

So for any $w=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, one always can choose $n\in Z$ such that

$z=\ln\rho+i(\theta+2n\pi)\in\mathbb{C}\setminus B$; namely $f(z)=e^z$ is from $\mathbb{C}\setminus B$ onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

From this I must deduce $g(z) = \cos(z)$ maps $\mathbb C / B$ onto $\mathbb C$ but I am failing to do so.

Am I just missing something very obvious, as I feel the hard part has been completed...

Comment: $e^z$ is periodic so any value taken inside bounded $B$ is taken outside $B$ by going enough periods away; same argument works for $\cos z$ as that is also periodic (and now takes all complex values by an easy quadratic equation argument)

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{iz} = \cos z \pm i\sqrt{1 - \cos^2 z}$$

If $B$ is bounded, so is $iB$.